# try: except: clauses not working with elif statements?

Tags: python

I am working through the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python course, and one of the lessons has me stumped, regarding the use of the try: and except: clauses.

When I run the code as described in the course below, using if/else statements it works, as the except clause is executed and python prints ' you did not enter a number' when entering text such as 'one'

```
print('how many cats do you have?')
numcats=input()
try:
    if int(numcats)>=4:
        print('that is a lot of cats')
    else:
        print('that is not many cats')
except ValueError:
    print('you did not enter a number')
```

however, when I use elif statements as per this example, the except clause is not executed, and I get an error. To me they both look like they should produce the same result.

What am I missing?

```
print('how many cats do you own?')
numcats=int(input())
try:    
    if numcats<=5 and numcats>0:
        print('that is not alot of cats')
    elif numcats >5 and numcats<=10:
            print('that is alot of cats! more than five and less than 10!')
    elif numcats <0:
            print('you cant have less than zero cats!')
    elif numcats>10:
            print('more than 10 cats! thats crazy!')
except ValueError:
    print('you did not enter a numerical value, try again')
```

I compared the structure of the two sets of code, and looks like they should produce the same result, not sure why the elif statements cause the except: clause to not be executed? I thought it would be the same as an if, else statement

Comment: anythings which is doubtful or reason to occur error , place it inside the try block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that produces a `ValueError` is the conversion of the input to integer (`int(numcats)` and `int(input())`). In the first example, you do it inside of the `try` block in the second before `try`, hence the error is not caught.

Move `numcats=int(input())` inside the `try` block and this should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This worked, I now see where I went wrong.  The error has to occur within the try block in order to have the except clause executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `int()` conversion inside `try:` block.

Something like this:

```py
while True:
    try:    
        numcats = int(input('how many cats do you own? '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('you did not enter a numerical value, try again')

if numcats <= 5 and numcats > 0:
    print('that is not alot of cats')
elif numcats > 5 and numcats <= 10:
    print('that is alot of cats! more than five and less than 10!')
elif numcats < 0:
    print('you cant have less than zero cats!')
elif numcats > 10:
    print('more than 10 cats! thats crazy!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

You use print but I think you must use input there

```
user_input = input("enter a number")

try : 
  numcats= int(user_input)
except ValueError:
  print ("enter a number")
else:
    if numcats<=5 and numcats>0:
        print('that is not alot of cats')
    elif numcats >5 and numcats<=10:
            print('that is alot of cats! more than five and less than 10!')
    elif numcats <0:
            print('you cant have less than zero cats!')
    elif numcats>10:
            print('more than 10 cats')
```

Comment: I forgot to add a int before the input ubright

Comment: Now, this should work. But your first comment is confusing. Why must you use input instead of print? And if so, why don't you use `input("enter a number")` instead of `print` in your code?

Comment: We want to show to user he must input a number it's working with one line of code input ! And why we must have two line code with print to show the user he must enter a number and second line to just a input ?

Comment: I made a mistake use input to name a user_input that was bad luck I just was on rush to answer a question fast and this things happen  I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Upvoting as now it is a working solution. Thank you for fixing it

Comment: thank you next time i will put more time to answer the questions to avoid  this type errors